# How to model formative latent variable in R using lavaan, and also add control variables

Tags: r, controls

I want to do a structural equation model for my analysis.

All three concepts are formative, which means these measurement variables construct the latent structure. Not reflective.

And also I want to control for demographic variables.

The analysis will use R and I learnt Lavaan in statistics class, just curious whether anyone can give more information on what I want to do.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 2):

in order to used formative constructs you need to use partial least square SEM (PLS-SEM) and not covariance based SEM (Cov-SEM).

the underlying assumption of the two technique differs, as PLS assumes that because the constructs are formative there is no error in measurement while CoV-SEM, has the defaults assumption of reflexive measurement and thus takes into account the error terms while analyzing the model

Lavaan package is a COV-SEM one, you can try plspm for using formative items

here there is a guide on how to use the plspm pakage:
http://gastonsanchez.com/PLS_Path_Modeling_with_R.pdf